# How to reset cooldown discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord, nextcord

I want to reset command cooldown (for slash commands)

```
@client.tree.command(name="my_command")
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 15, key=lambda i: (i.guild_id, i.user.id))
async def my_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    i = 1
    if i == 1:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Cooldown shouldn't apply")
    if i == 2:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Cooldown should apply ")
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
@client.tree.command(name="my_command")
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 15, key=lambda i: (i.guild_id, i.user.id))
async def my_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    i = 1
    if i == 1:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Cooldown shouldn't apply")
        my_command.reset_cooldown(ctx)
    if i == 2:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Cooldown should apply ")
```

Comment: Unresolved reference 'ctx'